# How to include transiant depedency of springboot inside fabric mod

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, minecraft-fabric

I want to use spring boot inside fabric mod. And it works while I'm runing my minecraft server with `gradlew.bat runServer` command. But when I'm using `gradlew.bat build` and put the production jar inside a real server I got no class deff found error. Like that :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not execute entrypoint stage 'server' due to errors, provided by 'litopia_services'!
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
       at fr.litopia.services.LitopiaServices.onInitializeServer(LitopiaServices.java:23) ~[litopia-services-1.0.0.jar:?]
```

And it's seems leagite cause inside the jar that gradle build there is'nt spring boot transiant depencency.

So to prevent this issue I have to use `api` insted of `include` or `implement include` but none of that have work actually my build.gradle looks like that :

```
plugins {
   id 'fabric-loom' version '0.11-SNAPSHOT'
   id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.14'
   id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.15.RELEASE'
}

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

archivesBaseName = project.archives_base_name
version = project.mod_version
group = project.maven_group

repositories {
   // Add repositories to retrieve artifacts from in here.
   // You should only use this when depending on other mods because
   // Loom adds the essential maven repositories to download Minecraft and libraries from automatically.
   // See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
   // for more information about repositories.
   maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
   maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
   maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifac' }
   maven { url 'https://zoidberg.ukp.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/artifactory/public-releases' }
   maven { url 'https://maven.terraformersmc.com/releases' }
   mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
   springBom
   compileOnly.extendsFrom(springBom)
   annotationProcessor.extendsFrom(springBom)
   implementation.extendsFrom(springBom)
   all {
      // We need to use fabric implementation of log4j
      exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
   }
}

dependencies {
   // To change the versions see the gradle.properties file
   minecraft "com.mojang:minecraft:${project.minecraft_version}"
   mappings "net.fabricmc:yarn:${project.yarn_mappings}:v2"
   modImplementation "net.fabricmc:fabric-loader:${project.loader_version}"

   // Fabric API. This is technically optional, but you probably want it anyway.
   modImplementation "net.fabricmc.fabric-api:fabric-api:${project.fabric_version}"

   // Spring boot dependencies
   springBom enforcedPlatform('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.5.14')

   api include('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
   implementation include('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.5.14')
   implementation include('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
   implementation include('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket')

   // OpenAPI swagger
   implementation include('org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.13')

   // Spring discord api
   implementation include('com.discord4j:discord4j-core:3.2.3')
}

processResources {
   inputs.property "version", project.version

   filesMatching("fabric.mod.json") {
      expand "version": project.version
   }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
   it.options.release = 17
}

java {
   // Loom will automatically attach sourcesJar to a RemapSourcesJar task and to the "build" task
   // if it is present.
   // If you remove this line, sources will not be generated.
   withSourcesJar()
}

jar {
   from("LICENSE") {
      rename { "${it}_${project.archivesBaseName}"}
   }
}
```